# Create and coding animator script with Unity

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, animator

i have a three animation state and two bool parameters.
I want to circle of that.

The entry state "BeklemeAtakYap" there is in nothing animation.

Firstly, i set bool "Bekle" true, "Saldir" false.

The animation starting "Bekleme" state.

I am setting on the script "Bekle" false and "Saldir" true.

Animation contiunning "Saldir" state.

And i make a translation "Saldir" and "BeklemeAtakYap".

When the "Saldir" state end and the "BeklemeAtakYap" starting, i want the bool parameters "Bekle" true "Saldir" false how can do that?[image: The circle animation]

Answer (score 0):

You can add an AnimationEvent at the end of Saldir state.

just right click on the top of the timeline just below times and select add AnimationEvent.

Then write a function in a script which is attached to the AnimationController and assign it to the AnimationEvent. In that function you can manually set animation parameters.

`GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("Saldir", false);`

By the way please use English words in your question for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

I click "BeklemeAtakYap" state and click the Add Behavior-> Add Script. 
Open the script and write;

```
override public void OnStateEnter(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex) {
    animator.SetBool ("Saldir", false);
    animator.SetBool ("Bekle", true);
}
```

That's work.